# How do I make new fields appear in the form based upon the selection of two different dropdown values in InfoPath 2010

Tags: infopath-form

I'm new to using InfoPath. I am looking to have new fields (both the label and control) appear in the form based upon two different drop-down values. I tried with formatting rule option but the section is visible when the form load, but my requirement is to be the section should be visible only when the two drop-down values are selected.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the formatting like:

- **drop down field is empty** > Hide this control
- or **drop down field containts "default value"** > Hide this control

[image]